# Spliterator: Thread-Safe or not?

Tags: java-8, iterator, thread-safety, java-stream, spliterator

I am looking into the documentation of the Spliterator and according to it, the Spliterator is not thread-safe:

> Despite their obvious utility in parallel algorithms, spliterators are not expected to be thread-safe; instead, implementations of parallel algorithms using spliterators should ensure that the spliterator is only used by one thread at a time. This is generally easy to attain via serial thread-confinement, which often is a natural consequence of typical parallel algorithms that work by recursive decomposition.

But, in its further documentation, which states a contradictory statement to the above statement:

> Structural interference of a source can be managed in the following ways (in approximate order of decreasing desirability):
>
> The source manages concurrent modifications.
> For example, a key set of a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap is a concurrent source. A Spliterator created from the source reports a characteristic of CONCURRENT.

So does that mean a Spliterator generated from a thread-safe collection would be thread-safe? Is it right?

Comment: I see no contradiction in these two statements: `Spliterator` is _not required_ to be thread safe, but it _can be_ thread-safe. And if it is thread-safe, it may report that it has `CONCURRENT` characteristic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, a `Spliterator` reporting the `CONCURRENT` characteristic will have a thread safe *source*, which implies that it can iterate over it safely even when the source gets modified concurrently. But the `Spliterator` itself may still have state that must not be manipulated concurrently.

Note that your cite stems from a description of how “structural interference of a source can be managed”, not about the spliterator’s behavior in general.

This is also provided at the [documentation of the `CONCURRENT` characteristic itself](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#CONCURRENT):

> Characteristic value signifying that the element source may be safely concurrently modified (allowing additions, replacements, and/or removals) by multiple threads without external synchronization. If so, the Spliterator is expected to have a documented policy concerning the impact of modifications during traversal.

Nothing else.

So the consequences of these characteristics are astonishing small. A `Spliterator` reporting either `CONCURRENT` or `IMMUTABLE` will never throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`, that’s all. In all other regards, the differences between these characteristics will not be recognized by the `Stream` API, as the `Stream` API never performs any source manipulations, in fact, it doesn’t actually know the source (other than indirectly through the `Spliterator`), so it couldn’t do such manipulations nor detect whether a concurrent modification has happened.